# @Configuration and Bean property setting annotations

Tags: spring

I'm using @Configuration to create beans and set their properties from other bean properties such as is possible with xml configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(@Value("#{someObject.value}") double value) {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        myBean.setValue(value);
        return myBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeObject someObject() {
        SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
        someObject.setValue(1.0);
        return someObject;
    }
}
```

However, it is cumbersome and unnecessary to have to use the setter methods [eg. myBean.setValue(value)].  Instead I want something like so:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @MysticalPropertySetter(name="value", value="#{someObject.value}")
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @MysticalPropertySetter(name="value", value="1.0", type="java.lang.Double")
    public SomeObject someObject() {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
}
```

Anything like this possible?  Much Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this approach impossible because in your factory method annotated with @Bean you create objects manually, but Spring can inject properties only to beans that are instanteated by itself.

Comment: Spring should be able to set the properties on the bean *after* it's returned from the factory method.  I don't see an issue, it must be possible, if just not yet implemented.

Comment: May be I am wrong, but I have never seen or hear about such future. As I know, Spring just register object in container after it's returning from the factory method.  It don't give a possibility to set properties after returning as you noted. You can only pass properties as input arguments of the factory method and set them manually like you do. (similar thing when you use xml configuration).

Comment: And, by the way, I checked again Spring reference documentation and found that they also in their examples injects properties values in the Configuration class using @Value annotation and then in factory method set them manually to cteated class.

Answer (score 0):

How about constructor injection?

```
@Bean
public MyBean myBean(@Value("#{someObject.value}") double value) {
    return new MyBean(value);
}
```